# Vertical Navigation Bar

Tags: html, format, navbar

I'm trying to make a nav bar out of a un-ordered list.  This list needs to be vertical and pulled to the left side.  What I have now makes a vertical list all the way to the left, but it is on top of my content instead of to the left of it.

```
<ul id='help_links'>
    <li><a href="#annoucements">Announcements</a></li>
    <li><a href="#approvals">Approvals</a></li>
    #...
</ul>

<div id='content' style='margin:20px auto;'>
  <a name="annoucements"><h2>Announcements</h2></a>
  <h3>Creating Annoucements</h3>
  <ul style="list-style-type:circle;">
    <li>...</li>
#...
  </div>

#help_links ul
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#help_links li{
    display:block;
}
```

What do I need to change to get the content in the middle and have the help_links be listed to the left side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the list in a div, let's call its class a divlink and add this to your css:

```
div.divlink
{
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
}
div.content
{
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Oh and also after doing this, you should use padding instead of margin in your content div. From my experience, margins work weird with float.